# Bootstrap validation is not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have a form which is open in new mode and also in edit mode in jquery UI popup but validation works for me when my form open in new mode but when the same form open in edit mode validation not works I am stuck here and can't figure it out the way out. Any Help??

frmSpecialtyDetail form:

```
<div id="specialtyDetail">

<div class="fadeoutPatch0"></div>
<div class="fadeoutBackground" id="fbspecialtyDetail"></div>

<div id="tblspecialtyDetail" class="col-md-12">

    <form method="post" id="frmSpecialtyDetail" onsubmit="return false">
        <!--start - CONTENTS-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">Short Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input class="form-control size100" name="ShortName" id="txtShortName" type="text" maxlength="10" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 pad-a-labelsize">
                <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="chkActive">
                    <label for="Active">Active</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="txtDescription" type="text" maxlength="55" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 pad-a-labelsize-btn">
            <div class="btn-block">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Save</button>
                <!--<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="reset" onclick="specialtyDetail.SpecialtyUnload();">Cancel</button>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#frmSpecialtyDetail')
       .bootstrapValidator({
           message: 'This value is not valid',
           feedbackIcons: {
               valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
               invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
               validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
           },
           fields: {
               ShortName: {
                   group: '.col-md-6',
                   validators: {
                       notEmpty: {
                           message: 'Short Name is required'
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       })
    .on('success.form.bv', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       specialtyDetail.SpecialtySave();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you creating the jquery-ui popup..? Can you create an online demo using the inbuilt code snippet option or other tools such as jsfiddle..?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Boostrap Validator and implement to your code..

here is the documentation

http://bootstrapvalidator.com/getting-started/